# Help identifying a cartoon featuring a girl riding a giant green worm

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

This was an an English-language children's cartoon from the 1980s or earlier.

It featured a girl with pigtails riding through underground tunnels on a gigantic (sandworm-sized?) green worm.

Comment: I'm certain she can do better than that. When did she watch it? What age/ethnicity was the girl? Did she ride the worm bareback or on a saddle? Where did she ride the worm underground (through tunnels, in a cavern)? Was the worm bright green (luminous) or a dull green colour? What size was the worm ([sandworm size](https://youtu.be/WVqXE9ZY5wk?t=2m3s) or [horse-sized](https://youtu.be/nmjYodDqNAk?t=11s)? Why was she riding the worm? What language did she watch it in? Was it western-style animation of japanese style manga? Was it a cartoon aimed at adults (with nudity) or children? etc.

Comment: It was in English, a children's cartoon, and I don't think it was dubbed. She watched it in the 80's so it's from then or earlier. I'd say more sandworm sized and generally through tunnels.

Comment: Can she remember anything about the girl? Was she a child or older? Was she white/black? What colour was her hair? Did she speak at all?

Comment: It was from 30 years ago so her memory is a little hazy, it took a while to rule out caterpillar. I'll ask her what else she can remember tomorrow. I'm pretty sure both her and the worm spoke but I'll double check.

Comment: Flora from Jayce and the Wheeled Warriors? - https://youtu.be/9VR0kKRDr7I?t=14m7s?

Comment: Don't think so, she rides a car, not anything green that crawls.

Comment: Have a look at the video. She also rides on a sort of flying fish/worm thing.

Answer (score 4):

Solved. Turns out it was Guph's Giant Dirt-Devouring Worm in a few episodes of [The Wonderful Wizard of Oz (1986)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wonderful_Wizard_of_Oz_(1986_TV_series)) such as [Gnomes on the March](https://youtu.be/bD_42m6cn14) and was more of a blueish colour with perhaps a tinge of green.

Answer (score 0):

Nausicaä of the Valley of the Wind

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on your reasoning as to why you believe this to be the correct answer, like a quote or a screen shot?