# Kid's fantasy cartoon featuring giant subterranean worms which eat rock

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember watching a cartoon TV series when I was a kid (90's I think, or very early 2000's) on Australian TV. It was a fantasy setting, but the one strong memory I have is of subterranean caverns with structures (temples etc.) and it featured giant burrowing worms which would eat through solid rock.

I believe the protagonists were children, but I am not sure how many main protagonists were featured (maybe a boy and a girl?).

I cannot really recall any other settings or tableaus from the series - I believe my memory of the worms was of a couple of scenes where they blindly burrow through to an underground city and destroy everything in their wake (I remember them chewing through temple columns and then gobbling up the broken pieces).

Comment: Whilst you have a nice start here it is quite terse at the moment. Could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, you say you have a strong memory of that scene but do you have any weaker memories of other scenes or details in the work? Also do you know if this was a series, a one off or a movie?

Comment: Some elements of this are reminiscent of the Star Trek episode 'The devil in the dark' - specifically the creature which ate its way through solid rock, and the subterranean structures of the mining colony

Comment: Thanks @TheLethalCarrot - post edited. Unfortunately I can't squeeze any further memories out of my brain at the moment - will update if that changes!

Comment: Sounds like similar elements @MartinGoldsack, but I'm sure it wasn't Star Trek

Comment: [It's a long shot but does this look familiar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz2Cx.png)?

Comment: I don't think that's it. Considering how long ago it was the visual aesthetic of the actual show could be completely different from what's in my mind's eye, but I'm fairly sure that's something else.

Comment: There are caverns and a earth eating work but it seems to be controlled. Could be [this one though](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVEWs.png)?

Comment: Actually I think that might be it - are you able to confirm any details?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### [*The Wonderful Wizard of Oz*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092486/?ref_=tt_ov_inf) (originally titled *Ozu no Mahotsukai*) (1986 & 1987)

Specifically it appears to be episode 47 ["[G]Nomes On The March"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1840855/?ref_=ttep_ep34) ("Bakekubi abare ru"/"Bakekubi Goes on a Rampage"). A picture of the worm can be seen below.

[image: Image showing the worm]

It actually appears to be an anime rather than a cartoon and was dubbed and released in Canada later on.

And the full episode can be seen on YouTube here:

---

I actually found this from the "Related" section on the side on the question: [Help identifying a cartoon featuring a girl riding a giant green worm](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/124595/58193)

Comment: Thanks very much for digging this up. The scenes with the worm were strongly familiar to me, but the other content of this episode not so much. However when I watch the title/end sequences which obviously include scenes from across the series, I see more familiar images. Looking at the Wikipedia article it says that ABC (national Australian broadcaster) ran it in the early 90's. I had no idea it was based on the Wizard of Oz. When I saw the title in your post I was immediately skeptical, but this is it.

Comment: This has been a memory of mine as well, in the same way where the worm sequences are etched in more than anything else around it. How curious. Is this the most memorable part of the series or was there something funny about the way it was broadcast on Australia?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will see this late reply, because I am under the impression you mean Nausicaa of the valley of the Wind. A friend of mine had the exact same recollection and experience as you did as a child, his description was identical. In the end he actually meant this film (now available for streaming in Australia actually).

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Firstly, OP already accepted an answer last year, so it would appear they've already found the cartoon they were looking for. Secondly, you should explain how *Nausicaa of the Valley of the Wind* matches the OP's description.

Comment: Thanks for bringting this up @Dejavu. Nausicaa of the Valley of the Wind doesn't look familiar to me, and I am sure that TheLethalCarrot's answer is the series from my memory. However it sounds fascinating & I am keen to check it out anyway!